# Google Drive file properties - how to set multiple properties in one request?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Using the following API allows you to obtain multiple properties assigned to a file:

```
props = service.properties().list(fileId=fileId).execute().get('items', [])
```

However, I don't see any way to set multiple properties.  Is this just missing from the documentation, or have Google really overlooked this?

Comment: I know in the Java client lib you can setProperties (plural) and pass in a List of Property resources. I looked around but couldn't find great documentation of that, or the python equivalent, but it leads me to think you can list multiple Property resources when inserting a File in general

Comment: In case anyone needs it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62565513/13809128) is the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of properties as a list, rather than a map. So the answer is no.

To save http traffic you could batch your requests as described here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch

Comment: This answer is outdated. You can now set multiple properties via the file.update method