# Google Drive Python API: Adding Multiple Properties

Tags: google-drive-api

This question is in reference to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/947) issue.

I would like to add multiple entries into the `properties` metadata field for a file so that the file is indexable using `files().list()`. Here is my code:

```py
# define read and write permissions

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

# check if the user's access and refresh tokens already exist

import pickle
import os

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle','rb') as f:
        creds = pickle.load(f)
else:
    creds = None

"""
If the user's access and refresh tokens don't exist, or they are no longer valid, then create them and save them. This will not work if the credentials.json file is not in the user's working directory.
"""

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(creds,f)

"""
check that the authentication flow worked. This should be the same as the string in the "client_id" field in the credentials.json file. Additionally, if the access and refresh tokens did not already exist, then a token.pickle file should now be in the user's working directory.
"""

print('client_id is: {}'.format(creds.client_id))

# create a drive object to directly interface with the user's Google Drive.

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

drive = build('drive', 'v3',credentials=creds)

# create a folder in the root directory of the user's Google Drive.

folder_metadata = {
    
    'name': 'TestFolder',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    
}

folder = drive.files().create(body = folder_metadata, fields = 'id,name').execute()

# upload a file with indexable properties to the created folder

# first create the file
with open('HelloWorld.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('Hello World!')

# then define metadata
property1 = {'key' : 'day_of_week', 'value' : 'Monday'}
property2 = {'key' : 'patient_num', 'value' : '001'}

file_metadata = {
    'name': 'HelloWorld.txt',
    'parents': [folder['id']],
    'properties':[property1,property2]
}

# finally upload
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

media = MediaFileUpload('HelloWorld.txt',chunksize = -1,resumable = False)
file = drive.files().create(body = file_metadata, media_body = media, fields = 'name,properties').execute()

# try to search for the file

query = "properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}"

files_list = drive.files().list(q = query, fields = 'files(name,properties)').execute()
```

When I execute this code, `files_list` contains `{'files': []}`. The reason for this is because the `file` variable contains:

```
{'name': 'HelloWorld.txt',
 'properties': {'value': 'Monday', 'key': 'day_of_week'}}
```

Clearly, the `'patient_num'` property was not added to the `properties` field, even though it was explicitly defined in the `file_metadata` dictionary. I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038308/google-drive-file-properties-how-to-set-multiple-properties-in-one-request) on Stack Overflow, but I feel that the proposed solution is inefficient. How do I add multiple properties to a file so that it is indexable using either the `day_of_week` property or the `patient_num` property or both properties at the same time? Also, once I can do this, how should I modify `query` so that I am able to index using multiple properties simultaneously?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I think that in your script, it is required to modify the request body of `drive.files().create()`. Please modify from `'properties':[property1,property2]` to `'properties': {'day_of_week': 'Monday','patient_num': '001'}`, and test it again. In my environment, I could confirm that your script worked by this modification. I think that `query = "properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}"` can be used for this situation. If this was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks for your quick response. I already tried this [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/947#issuecomment-649089972). As you can see, I still cannot query multiple properties at once. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I'm confused. So I would like to confirm your current issue. 1. In your script, when the script is modified by above proposal, the script worked? 2. I cannot understand about `I still cannot query multiple properties at once`. In your script, I think that the single property is used for searching files like `{key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}`. You want to use other query like `properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'} or properties has {key = 'key1' and value = 'value1'}`?

Comment: This could be an intended behavior if it's related to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/149522397). Can you confirm if you get the proper results when doing two separate queries instead of one?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, when I modify the script as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/947#issuecomment-649089972), the `file['properties']` contains `{'patient_num': '001', 'day_of_week': 'Monday'}` which works as expected. However, the `query` throws an error in `files().list()` when I try to filter search results using multiple properties because the query format is wrong. To answer your last question, yes I want to know the correct query format to filter using multiple properties at once. Instead of `or` I want to use `and`.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, in addition to my last comment, the main goal of my project is to be able to filter a long list of files in my drive by their properties. For example, if I have 5 files and each of them has the properties `color`, `date`, and `time`, then I want to be able to filter these files based on these properties. For example, I want to be able to search `color = blue and date = 23/06/2020 and time = 18:00` and `files().list()` should return for me a list of files that match my search criteria. Note that I already set the `color`, `date`, and `time` properties for all the files.

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas, I tried two separate queries: `query = "properties has {key = 'day_of_week' and value = 'Monday'}"` and `query = "properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}"`. For each individual query, I executed `files_list = drive.files().list(q = query, fields = 'files(name,properties)').execute()` and both of them returned `HelloWorld.txt` as expected. This means that individual queries work fine. However, I want to be able to filter using multiple properties at once, not individually. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jescanellas in addition to my last comment, I want to be able to filter using both `day_of_week` and `patient_num` at the same time. For example, if I had 5 files with the same `day_of_week` values but  differerent `patient_num` values and if I had 5 other files with different `day_of_week` values and the same `patient_num` values, then I want to be able to filter search results using both `day_of_week` and `patient_num` at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query format for multiple properties in case anyone needs it.

```py
# try to search for the file

query = "properties has {key = 'day_of_week' and value = 'Monday'} and properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}"

files_list = drive.files().list(q = query, fields = 'files(name,properties)').execute()
```

The full working code is:

```py
# define read and write permissions

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

# check if the user's access and refresh tokens already exist

import pickle
import os

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle','rb') as f:
        creds = pickle.load(f)
else:
    creds = None

"""
If the user's access and refresh tokens don't exist, or they are no longer valid, then create them and save them. This will not work if the credentials.json file is not in the user's working directory.
"""

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(creds,f)

"""
check that the authentication flow worked. This should be the same as the string in the "client_id" field in the credentials.json file. Additionally, if the access and refresh tokens did not already exist, then a token.pickle file should now be in the user's working directory.
"""

print('client_id is: {}'.format(creds.client_id))

# create a drive object to directly interface with the user's Google Drive.

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

drive = build('drive', 'v3',credentials=creds)

# create a folder in the root directory of the user's Google Drive.

folder_metadata = {
    
    'name': 'TestFolder',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    
}

folder = drive.files().create(body = folder_metadata, fields = 'id,name').execute()

# upload a file with indexable properties to the created folder

# first create the file
with open('HelloWorld.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('Hello World!')

# then define metadata

properties = {
    'day_of_week' : 'Monday',
    'patient_num' : '001'
}

file_metadata = {
    'name' : 'HelloWorld.txt',
    'parents' : [folder['id']],
    'properties' : properties
}

# finally upload
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

media = MediaFileUpload('HelloWorld.txt',chunksize = -1,resumable = False)
file = drive.files().create(body = file_metadata, media_body = media, fields = 'name,properties').execute()

# try to search for the file

query = "properties has {key = 'day_of_week' and value = 'Monday'} and properties has {key = 'patient_num' and value = '001'}"

files_list = drive.files().list(q = query, fields = 'files(name,properties)').execute()
```

Note that the general format to query multiple properties at the same time is:

`"properties has {key = 'key1' and value = 'value1'} and properties has {key = 'key2' and value = 'value2'} and properties has {key = 'key3' and value = 'value3'} and ..."`

Hope this helps.